# Powershell foreach expression- Want comment in output

Tags: variables, powershell, foreach, comments

i am using the following PowerShell expression to Ping various machines in my company. $serverName are the IP's of the machines I want to ping (Around 25) and PS outputs the findings nicely as `172.172.172.172 is alive and pinging` on each line etc.

Is there a way I can have PowerShell output a comment I have given to each variable like below or the computername?

```
172.172.172.172 - Norwich PC1
192.192.192.192 # My PC is alive and Pinging
```

Thanks

```
$ServerName = 
"172.172.172.172",
"192.192.192.192"
"192.192.193.193"

foreach ($Server in $ServerName) {
             if (test-Connection -ComputerName $Server -Count 2 -Quiet ) { 
             write-Host "$Server is alive and Pinging " -ForegroundColor Green

            } else

            { Write-Warning "$Server Switched off not pinging "

            }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom Powershell objects but probably the easiest in this case would be to replace your list of addresses with some data in CSV format:

```
$Servers = @"
"Addr","Comment" 
"172.172.172.172","Norwich PC1"
"192.192.192.192","My PC"
"192.192.193.193",""
"@

foreach ($Server in (ConvertFrom-Csv $Servers)) {
             if (test-Connection -ComputerName $Server.addr -Count 2 -Quiet ) { 
             write-Host "$($Server.addr)($($Server.Comment)) is alive and Pinging " -ForegroundColor Green

            } else

            { Write-Warning "$($Server.addr)($($Server.Comment)) Switched off not pinging "

            }
}
```

You could also easily save the addresses in a separate file if you wanted in which case use `Import-Csv`.